# How to overcome "Specify image dimensions" gtmetrix performance summary message?

Tags: performance, magento, seo

I am working on a magento application.I am displaying the category images in the navigation menu.

I have assigned height and width to them using css.When I check for the performance in the getmetrix for the site ,I get *Specify image dimensions* message to increase the performance.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: you have to re-size image with your height and width because if original image width is 800px and height 300px and you assign with css something like this width:200px and height:50px but it takes orignal image h*w not your css h*w and page load time it change to your h*w

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three places that you should manage image dimensions

1) Anywhere you output product images (list.phtml, media.phtml, possibly view.phtml depending on your template).

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($this->getProduct(), 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(66); ?>" width="66" height="66" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel()) ?>" /></a>
```

2) If you use callout images in your layout.xml files. You'll need to set the image dimensions in the xml file like so:

```
<reference name="left">
        <block type="core/template" name="left.permanent.callout" template="callouts/left_col.phtml">
            <action method="setImgSrc">
                <src>images/media/col_left_callout.jpg</src>
            </action>
            <action method="setImgAlt" translate="alt" module="catalog">
                <alt>Flooring Supplies Brands</alt>
            </action>
            <action method="setImgHeight">
                <width>225</width>
            </action>
            <action method="setImgWidth">
                <width>195</width>
            </action>
            <action method="setLinkUrl">
                <url>brands.html</url>
            </action>
        </block>
    </reference>
```

And then render them in the callout phtml like so:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/media/col_right_callout.jpg') ?>" width="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgWidth()) ?>" height="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgHeight()) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__($this->getImgAlt()) ?>" style="display:block;" />
```

3) Within cms static blocks

I've written an article how to do #2 here [How to add image dimensions in Magento layout files](http://www.eddiemay.me.uk/2014/05/30/adding-image-dimensions-in-magento-layout-xml-files/)

Answer (score 1):

You have to give images dimension in html `<img src="/img.jpg" width="500" height="500" />`

Comment: is there any other alternative for the same.Because the category images may be of different sizes an giving the height and width may affect quality of image.

Comment: by jquery `$('img').each( function() { var findImgWidth = $(this).width(); var findImgHeight = $(this).height();
$(this).attr('width',findImgWidth);$(this).attr('height',findImgHeight);
} );` not tested hope works

Comment: the goal of setting these attributes is to speed up the loading time on the browser. Would not this code delay even further? Moreover, gtmetrix get angry if you run javascript before page load.